# How to send this Razor data to a javascript function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
foreach (var interest in Model.Interests)
    {
    <div>
        <span>@interest.SubjectName</span>
        @if (interest.Description.Length > 2)
        {
            <a data-bind="click(DATA)" href="#" title="View Details">details</a>
        }
    </div>

    }
```

I'm using Razor because I need to allow users without javascript to have read-only access to the site, so using a knockout/JS loop here isn't an option.

In this line:

```
<a data-bind="click(DATA)" href="#" title="View Details">details</a>
```

I'd like to take the current `interest` (razor object) and send it into the `click` function.  I just don't know the syntax.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what representation of the object you want to pass to your function.  If JSON will suffice, try this:

```
<a data-bind='@String.Format("click({0})", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interest))'
   href="#" title="View Details">details</a>
```

Then in your `click` function you can get the object like this:

```
function click(data) {
    var interest = JSON.parse(data);
}
```